# how to ftp a file from unix to a windows shared folder

Tags: shell, unix

Please guide me in creating a shell script in unix which will copy a file from unix folder (Ex: ABC/Users/FP.xls) to a Windows Shared folder/directory? Assuming that Windows shared directory access has already been provided. Please share your thoughts on this!!

Comment: You want `smbclient`, which is a command-line UNIX client for accessing windows shares with a syntax similar to FTP.

Comment: On linux systems you can also create a remote mount point to the [SMB share](http://serverfault.com/q/383013/216617). Or, setup an [FTP Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323384) on Windows. Which do you want?

Comment: @Peter...I am not trying to access files from windows share drive. I just wanted to copy a file from Unix to Windows Shared Folder.

Comment: @Elliott...I tried using the command line /usr/bin/smbclient -L myhostname but unable to list any SMB shares here in my Linux. I got an error 'Error NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_REFUSED'. To simplify it, is there a way we can write a shell script in Unix to copy the file to a windows shared drive (say for ex: path of windows shared drive is \\server\server.grp)?